# Projection of a vector in the column space of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to find the projection of the column vector $(-1,1)$ on the column space of matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$? Clearly $(-1,1)$ column vector is not in the column space of $A$. Also the two columns of matrix $A$ are not independent. So $A$ Transpose $A$ is not invertible. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Please can you use MathJax for to write your problem? And about your question you need calculate $\operatorname{Proj}_{\operatorname{col}(A)}(-1,1)$ where $\operatorname{col}(A)=\operatorname{span}\{(1,-1),(0,0) \}$.

Comment: Hint: Note that $\operatorname{col}(A)=\operatorname{span}\{(1,-1),(0,0)\}=\operatorname{span}\{(1,-1)\}$.So, a basis for $\operatorname{col}(A)$ is $\beta_{\operatorname{col}(A)}=\{(1,-1)\}$ and then a orthonomal basis for $\beta_{\operatorname{col}(A)}$ is $\beta_{\operatorname{col}(A)}^{ON}=\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,-1)\}$.

Comment: Now, use that $\operatorname{Proj}_{H}v=\langle u, v \rangle u$ where $\beta_{\operatorname{H}}^{ON}=\{u\}$ is a orthonormal basis for $H$.

Comment: first col in A is (1 0 ) and not(1 -1)

Comment: @suhanta Now, is it correct my edition of your problem?

Comment: yes. thanks a ton.

Comment: There isn't a unique projection. A projection is defined by the space it's mapping to and the space it's annihilating, i.e., the nullspace. Here only the range is given $\{(1,0)\}$.